# Java - regex to match any integer

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I'm having a problem having a regex that matches a String with any int.

Here's what I have:

```
if(quantityDesired.matches("\b\d+\b")){.......}
```

But Eclipse gives me:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

I've looked through other similar questions and I've tried using a double backslash but that doesn't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do* need to escape the backslashes in Java string literals:

```
"\\b\\d+\\b"
```

This of course only matches *positive* integers, not *any* integer as you said in your question. Was that your intention?

> I've looked through other similar questions and I've tried using a double backslash but that doesn't work.

Then you must also have another error. I guess the problem is that you want to use [`Matcher.find`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) instead of `matches`. The former searches for the pattern anywhere in the string, whereas the latter only matches if the *entire* string matches the pattern. Here's an example of how to use `Matcher.find`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(quantityDesired);
if (matcher.find()) { ... }
```

**Note**

If you did actually want to match the entire string then you don't need the anchors:

```
if (quantityDesired.matches("\\d+")) {.......}
```

And if you only want to accept integers that fit into a Java int type, you should use Integer.parseInt as [Seyfülislam mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641008/java-regex-to-match-any-integer/7641038#7641038), rather than parsing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a regex, you might look into [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Note: This works only for positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you prefer [Integer.parseInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method? It does what you want and it is more readable.

Comment: Watch out: parseInt fails for 9999999999999999999. Though the OP didn't specify if that is what he wants or not.